# get_post_class() not working well

Tags: functions

I am using the get_post_class to get the classes for my posts:

post-75 post type-post status-publish format-standard category-uncategorized entry one-third teaser first

The array returned however is not correct:

```
array (size=9)
  0 => string 'post-21' (length=7)
  1 => string 'post' (length=4)
  2 => string 'type-post' (length=9)
  3 => string 'status-publish' (length=14)
  4 => string 'format-standard' (length=15)
  6 => string 'category-uncategorized' (length=22)
  7 => string 'entry' (length=5)
  8 => string 'one-third teaser' (length=16)
  9 => string 'first' (length=5)
```

one-third and teaser should be in separate slots.

This is the code generating the classes, from Bill Erickson's Genesis Grid Loop plugin:

```
/**
 * Grid Loop Post Classes
 *
 * @author Bill Erickson
 * @link http://www.billerickson.net/a-better-and-easier-grid-loop/
 *
 * @param array $classes
 * @return array $classes
 */
function be_grid_loop_post_classes( $classes ) {
    global $wp_query;
    $grid_args = $this->be_grid_loop_pagination();
    if( ! $grid_args )
        return $classes;

    // Convert teaser column to a class
    $teaser_columns = array( '', '', 'one-half', 'one-third', 'one-fourth', 'one-fifth', 'one-sixth' );
    $teaser_column = $teaser_columns[$grid_args['teaser_columns']];

    // First Page Classes
    if( ! $wp_query->query_vars['paged'] ) {

        // Features
        if( $wp_query->current_post < $grid_args['features_on_front'] ) {
            $classes[] = 'feature';

        // Teasers
        } else {
            $classes[] = $teaser_column . ' teaser';
            if( 0 == ( $wp_query->current_post - $grid_args['features_on_front'] ) || 0 == ( $wp_query->current_post - $grid_args['features_on_front'] ) % $grid_args['teaser_columns'] )
                $classes[] = 'first';
        }

    // Inner Pages
    } else {

        // Features
        if( $wp_query->current_post < $grid_args['features_inside'] ) {
            $classes[] = 'feature';

        // Teasers
        } else {
            $classes[] = $teaser_column . ' teaser';
            if( 0 == ( $wp_query->current_post - $grid_args['features_inside'] ) || 0 == ( $wp_query->current_post - $grid_args['features_inside'] ) % $grid_args['teaser_columns'] )
                $classes[] = 'first';
        }

    }

    return $classes;
}
```

Comment: how are the `.one-third` and `.teaser` classes generated?

Comment: There is a problem with the code that is adding `one-third` and `teaser`. So far as I know those are not Core classes. Please post that relevant code.

Comment: Added the code generating the classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create that string with `$classes[] = $teaser_column . ' teaser';`

Use the following instead:

```
$classes[] = $teaser_column;
$classes[] = 'teaser';
```

Comment: Got it, works now. We could also have used array_push() in this case I believe.